# Adding a node into the middle of a relationship

Tags: neo4j

I have relationship like this:

```
(a:Groups)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP]-(p:Person)
```

I'd like to add a node into it so it'll be like

```
(a:Groups)<-[:IS_SUBGROUP]-(s:Subgroup)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP]-(p:Person)
```

I tried this code:

```
MATCH (a:Groups) WITH COLLECT(a) AS ds
FOREACH (d1 IN ds | MATCH (d1)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP]-(p:Person)
CREATE (d1)<-[:IS_SUBGROUP]-(s:Subgroup)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP]-(p))
```

But I can't use `MATCH` inside `FOREACH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trying to create the relationship for all instances of the existing relationship you can use:

```
MATCH (a:Groups)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]-(p:Person)
CREATE (a)<-[:IS_SUBGROUP]-(s:Subgroup)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP]-(p))
```

If you wanted to also remove the existing relationship you would modify it a little:

```
MATCH (a:Groups)<-[existing:IS_MEMBER_OF]-(p:Person)
CREATE (a)<-[:IS_SUBGROUP]-(s:Subgroup)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP]-(p)
DELETE existing
```

Comment makes perfect sense, to create a subgroup for every group:

```
MATCH (a:Groups)
CREATE (a)<-[:IS_SUBGROUP]-(s:Subgroup)
WITH a, s
MATCH (a)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]-(p:Person)
CREATE (s)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP]-(p)
```

Or if you only want to create subgroups where Members exist:

```
MATCH (a:Groups)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]-(p:Person)
CREATE (a)<-[:IS_SUBGROUP]-(s:Subgroup)
WITH a, s, p
CREATE (s)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP]-(p)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it looks like it creates a node between every pair Group - Person. But i need to create only 1 Subgroup for each group and connect every user from the group to subgroup.

Comment: Number of groups = number of subgroup

Comment: Thank you very match, I was trying to use foreach, and that was my mistake. It's looks really simple)